# KendoUI chart custom data points

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Using the HTML5 version of KendoUI DataViz, is it possible to change the shape of the data points on a line or plot chart? They default as a circle I'm wondering if it would be possible to make them a square or some other shape?

Not sure if a css hack would be necessary, or if there is a method available to change them. I couldn't seem to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible you need to configure the marker type of the series which you want to change. [Here](http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/api/dataviz/chart#seriesmarkerstype-stringdefault) is the part of the documentation that you need.

You can choose between square, triangle and circle.

http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/api/dataviz/chart#seriesmarkerstype-stringdefault

Comment: Much appreciated! No clue how I was missing that.